# React Routing unable to route properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a route for admin pages. Codes can be found below. My current issue is that my currentUser has my authenticated user obj and userType is False, but I still can access /createUser page.

AdminRoute.js

```
import React from 'react' 
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom' 
import { useAuth } from '../../contexts/AuthContext' 
 
const AdminRoute = (props) => { 
    const { currentUser } = useAuth(); 
    const userType = localStorage.getItem('admin'); 
 
    if (currentUser === undefined) { 
        return null; 
    } 
    console.log(userType) 
 
    return currentUser && userType 
    ? ( 
      <Route {...props} /> 
    ) 
    : ( 
      <Redirect to={{ 
        pathname: "/homepage", 
        state: { 
          from: props.location 
        } 
      }} /> 
    ) 
} 
 
export default AdminRoute
```

Route.js

```
<Router> 
     <Switch>                
          <AdminRoute path='/createUser' component={Register} /> 
     </Switch>
</Router>
```

Step 1:
Login.js

```
async function handleSubmit(e) { 
        e.preventDefault() 
        try { 
            setError('') 
            setLoading(true) 
            await login(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value) 
 
            history.push('/homepage') 
        } catch { 
            console.log("heh") 
        } 
 
        setLoading(false) 
    }
```

Step 2: HandleSubmit will call function from AuthContext.js.

This is the AuthContext.js where I get the currentUser after authenticating at firebase

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react" 
import { auth, database } from "../firebase"; 
import { getDocs, query, where } from "firebase/firestore"; 
 
const AuthContext = React.createContext() 
 
export function useAuth() { 
    return useContext(AuthContext) 
} 
 
export function AuthProvider({ children }) { 
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null) 
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true) 
 
    function login(email, password) { 
        return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => { 
            const Doc = query(database.usersRef, where("email", "==", email)); 
 
            getDocs(Doc).then((querySnapshot) => { 
                let values = ''; 
 
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => { 
                    values = doc.id; 
                    
                    // Setting user type in session storage 
                    if (doc.data().userType === "Administrator") { 
                        localStorage.setItem('admin', false); 
                    } else { 
                        localStorage.setItem('admin', false); 
                    }
                }); 
 
                var userUpdate = database.usersRef.doc(values); 
                userUpdate.update({ 
                    lastActive: new Date().toLocaleString('en-SG'), 
                }) 
            }) 
        }); 
    } 
 
    function logout() { 
        return auth.signOut(); 
    } 
 
    function forgetPassword(email) { 
        return auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email); 
    } 
 
    function updateEmail(email) { 
        return currentUser.updateEmail(email) 
    } 
 
    function updatePassword(password) { 
        return currentUser.updatePassword(password) 
    } 
 
    function updateDisplayName(name) { 
        return currentUser.updateDisplayName(name) 
    } 
 
    useEffect(() => { 
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged( user => { 
            setLoading(false) 
            setCurrentUser(user) 
        }) 
 
        return unsubscribe 
    }, []) 
 
    const value = { 
        currentUser, 
        login, 
        forgetPassword, 
        logout, 
        updateEmail, 
        updatePassword, 
        updateDisplayName, 
    } 
 
    return ( 
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}> 
            {!loading && children} 
        </AuthContext.Provider> 
    ) 
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [this one](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/auth), it might help you. Try to go with live example.

Comment: Can look at your implementation for useAuth hook

Comment: Hi @MUGABA, I added in the useAuth

Comment: I see where you retrieve a `userType` with `const userType = localStorage.getItem('admin');`, where do you set this value into localStorage? Is this even needed? Does the `currentUser` object not encapsulate a user's "roles"?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, I set this when user logs in. This data is taken from firestore and not firebase auth in this case. So its not encap in currentUser obj

Comment: The `login` function has asynchronous code that you might not be waiting on. All the auth "state" might also not be getting initialized correctly when the app mounts. Can you provide an exact set of reproduction steps to induce the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the issue. The code is not JSON serializing/deserializing the `"admin"` state it is persisting and loading from localStorage.

In your console run:

```
localStorage.setItem('admin', false)
const userType = localStorage.getItem('admin')
typeof userType
userType
```

[image]

`localStorage.getItem('admin');` returns a JSON string, `"false"`, and when you console log it you don't see the quotes. `"false"` is a truthy value, so the `currentUser && userType` boolean expression evaluates `true` when a user is authenticated and there was a value stored in localStorage under the `"admin"` key.

You should always JSON serialize/deserialize to/from localStorage.

```
const AdminRoute = (props) => { 
  const { currentUser } = useAuth(); 
  const userType = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('admin') ?? false); 
 
  if (currentUser === undefined) { 
    return null; 
  } 
 
  return currentUser && userType 
    ? ( 
      <Route {...props} /> 
    ) 
    : ( 
      <Redirect to={{ 
        pathname: "/homepage", 
        state: { 
          from: props.location 
        } 
      }} /> 
    );
}
```

login

```
...

// Setting user type in session storage 
localStorage.setItem('admin', JSON.stringify(doc.data().userType === "Administrator"));
```